# Improper fraction

Tags: fractions

Do the improper fractions include, "the fraction whose numerator is **greater than or equal** its denominator" or "the fraction whose numerator is **greater only** than the denominator"?

Comment: If they are equal, then the fraction equals one, so I don't think there is much use for calling it a fraction anymore.

Comment: It means whatever the person using it says it means. If the person using it doesn't say what it means, then it is anyone's guess. Does it really matter?

Comment: I do understand what you are saying, bu I am asking about the definition, mainly.

Comment: What do you mean by "the definition"? Different people may use the term to mean different things. The purpose of a definition is to make it clear to everyone what terms mean. So, if you use the term, make it clear what you mean. End of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any fraction that would reduce to an integer and fraction, is an improper fraction.  So 8/8 and 9/8 are both improper fractions, while 7/8 is a proper fraction.

Answer (score 0):

It should be stated at the beginning of your paper, whether you consider $\frac{a}{a}$ as an improper fraction od not. Point it out and continue with the convention you have just set on your work.

Answer (score 0):

A fraction with a numerator that is greater than or equal to the denominator is known as an improper fraction. It represents a number greater than or equal to one.